# RefreshToken not working as expecting in ktor

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor

Hey I am working in Ktor in KMM. I tried to use [refreshToken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71934975/11560810) as per suggestion for authentication in my application.

**HttpClient.kt**

```
package com.example.kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule

import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.call.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.okhttp.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.auth.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.auth.providers.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.logging.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

actual fun httpClient(config: HttpClientConfig<*>.() -> Unit) = HttpClient(OkHttp) {
    config(this)
    install(Logging) {
        logger = Logger.SIMPLE
        level = LogLevel.BODY
    }
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json(Json {
            prettyPrint = true
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
            explicitNulls = false
        })
    }
    engine {
        config {
            retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            readTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        }
    }
    defaultRequest {
        header("Client-Version", Platform().versionCode)
    }
    install(Auth) {
        bearer {
            loadTokens {
                BearerTokens(tokenProvider.accessToken, "")
            }
            refreshTokens {
                val response =
                    client.post("https://vivek-modi.com/api/v1/session/refresh") {
                        contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
                        setBody(KtorSessionCommand(tokenProvider.refreshToken))
                    }
                if (response.status == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) {
                    println("application will logout")
                    null
                } else {
                    println("application in else part")
                    val ktorLoginResponse = response.body<KtorLoginResponse>()
                    ktorLoginResponse.ktorAccessToken?.let { ktorAccessToken ->
                        ktorAccessToken.accessToken?.let { accessToken ->
                            ktorAccessToken.refreshToken?.let { refreshToken ->
                                BearerTokens(accessToken, refreshToken)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlinx-serialization")
}

version = "1.0"

kotlin {
    android()
    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    iosSimulatorArm64()

    cocoapods {
        summary = "Some description for the Shared Module"
        homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "14.1"
        framework {
            baseName = "kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val ktorVersion = "2.0.0"
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-default-headers:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-auth:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:1.3.2")
                implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-core:3.2.0-beta-1")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-jvm:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-native:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk = 32
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 32
    }
}
```

**Expected Output**

**Scenario 1**

> when my main api return 401, I need to call `https://vivek-modi.com/api/v1/session/refresh` if this return different then 401 status, then I need to call my main api again.

**Scenario 2**

> when my main api return 401, I need to call `https://vivek-modi.com/api/v1/session/refresh` if this return 401, I need to logout my application.

**Actual Ouput**

I am calling api in button click.

1. So when I click 1st time on button, it called my main api, which return 401. So **refreshToken** call `https://vivek-modi.com/api/v1/session/refresh` which return 401. I used **println** to print message in console but it not printing the message.

[image]

2. when I click 2nd time or more time on button. It call only my main api. It not calling my refresh api.

[image]

Can someone guide me please. How can I achieve my expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that a client (specifically the `Auth` plugin) tries to infinitely refresh a token. Here is the [comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-3795/Bearer-Auth:-refreshTokens-callback-blocks-indefinitely-when-ser#focus=Comments-27-5804576.0-0) from the corresponding issue:

> When refresh token request fails with 401 it tries to refresh token again, resulting in an infinite cycle. Since token refreshing is a users' code, users need to mark such requests, so we can have a special case.

To solve it you need to call `markAsRefreshTokenRequest()` inside the request builder:

```
val response =
    client.post("https://vivek-modi.com/api/v1/session/refresh") {
        markAsRefreshTokenRequest()
        contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
        setBody(KtorSessionCommand(tokenProvider.refreshToken))
    }
```

Comment: Note that you can only call `markAsRefreshTokenRequest()` from the `refreshToken {}` block