# Handle refreshToken on both 401 & 403 in ktor-clilent android

Tags: android, android-jetpack, ktor, ktor-client

I am using ktor for my android app and its working fine now we have a new requirement that we need to handle the responseCode 401 or 403. For example if we hit getUsersAPI() call and it got 401 or 403 then we need to hit refreshToken API call and if refreshToken API call is successful then call failed API again with new tokens else logout user.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71946014/refreshtoken-not-working-as-expecting-in-ktor?rq=4) is exactly my usecase but only thing is refreshToken should be called on 401 & 403.

```
  private fun httpClient() = HttpClient(engine = configuration.engine()) {
        configuration.requestRetry?.let { config ->
            val configuration: HttpRequestRetryConfig = HttpRequestRetryConfig().apply(config)

            install(HttpRequestRetry) {
                configuration.maxRetry?.let { maxRetries ->
                    val max = maxRetries.invoke()
                    /**
                    retryOnException: It will retry on all exception except cancellation exception
                     */
                    retryOnException(
                        maxRetries = max,
                        retryOnTimeout = configuration.retryOnTimeout.invoke()
                    )

                    /**
                    retry if status is not success: it will retry is status code is not [200, 300]
                     */
                    retryIf(maxRetries = max) { _, response ->
                        !response.status.isSuccess()
                    }
                }
                exponentialDelay()
                modifyRequest {
                    request.headers.append("x-retry-count", retryCount.toString())
                }
            }
        }
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(
                Json {
                    ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                    encodeDefaults = true
                    isLenient = true
                    prettyPrint = true
                    explicitNulls = false
                },
            )
        }
        Logging {
            logger = object : Logger {
                override fun log(message: String) {
                    if (configuration.logging) {
                        httpMetrics.log(message)
                    }
                }
            }
            level = LogLevel.ALL
        }
        install(HttpTimeout) {
            requestTimeoutMillis = timeoutConfig.requestTimeoutMillis
            connectTimeoutMillis = timeoutConfig.connectTimeoutMillis
            socketTimeoutMillis = timeoutConfig.socketTimeoutMillis
        }
        defaultRequest {
            url {
                protocol = URLProtocol.createOrDefault(environment.protocol)
                host = environment.baseUrl
            }
            contentType(configuration.contentType)
        }
        HttpResponseValidator {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            expectSuccess = this@HttpClient.expectSuccess
            validateResponse { response ->

                val statusCode = response.status.value
                val originCall = response.call
                if (statusCode == 204 /*|| statusCode == 201*/) throw AppException(
                    ErrorResponse(
                        statusCode.toString(),
                        NO_DATA_FOUND
                    )
                )
                if (statusCode < 300 || originCall.attributes.contains(ValidateMark)) {
                    return@validateResponse
                }

                if (statusCode == 401 || statusCode == 403) {
                    println("HANDLE ERROR HERE FOR REFFRESS------------------------------------>>")
                }
                val exceptionCall = originCall.save().apply {
                    attributes.put(ValidateMark, Unit)
                }

                val exceptionResponse = exceptionCall.response
                val exceptionResponseText = try {
                    exceptionResponse.bodyAsText()
                } catch (_: MalformedInputException) {
                    BODY_FAILED_DECODING
                }
                print(exceptionResponseText)
                val errorResponse = Json.decodeFromString<ErrorResponse>(exceptionResponseText)
                throw AppException(errorResponse)
            }
        }

        install(Auth) {
            bearer {
                sendWithoutRequest { request ->
                    request.url.host == "www.googleapis.com"
                }
                loadTokens {
                    val token = authToken().accessToken.orEmpty()
                    val refreshToken = authToken().refreshToken.orEmpty()
                    BearerTokens(accessToken = token, refreshToken = refreshToken)
                }
                refreshTokens {
                    val workEmail = authToken().workEmail.orEmpty()
                    val refreshToken = authToken().refreshToken.orEmpty()
                    val response = client.post {
                        markAsRefreshTokenRequest()
                        this.apply(
                            RefreshToken(
                                refreshTokenId = "",
                                refreshToken = refreshToken,
                                email = workEmail,
                                deviceId = deviceId!!
                            )
                        )
                    }
                    if (response.status == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized || response.status == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden) {
                        println("application will logout")
                        null
                    } else {
                        println("application in else part")
                        val ktorLoginResponse = response.body<RefreshTokenModel>()

                        ktorLoginResponse.data?.let { ktorAccessToken ->
                            ktorAccessToken.token?.let { accessToken ->
                                ktorAccessToken.refreshToken?.let { refreshToken ->
                                    BearerTokens(accessToken, refreshToken)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I get this working. PLease suggest me what I am doing wrong

Comment: Does the `refreshTokens`'s block get executed on the 401 response from the server?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, From server I am always getting 403 only so I am unable to test that.

Comment: The `Auth` plugin with the `BearerAuthProvider` refreshes the token only when the server responds with the 401 status code and the appropriate `WWW-Authenticate` header. So you seem to do everything correctly, but the use case with 403 isn't supported.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how I can cater this usecase with ktor?

Comment: The only way I see is to copy the code of the `Auth` plugin and adjust it for your use case. Here is the line of code where the status is checked (https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/49e02046a68801d85c7e57900ebe1cbf7b173364/ktor-client/ktor-client-plugins/ktor-client-auth/common/src/io/ktor/client/plugins/auth/Auth.kt#L138).

Comment: @AlekseiTirman I have checked the code in the link you provided but still not getting it. So far What I have acheived is I am able to call the refreshToken on 401 & 403 after successful response I have saved the token as well but how to retry the failed request is what I am not able to acomplished. Sharing the code for your reference in another comment, It will be really helpful if you share your inputs.

Comment: This is the code I have used to rexecute the request but I am getting  'java.lang.illegalstateexception fail to prepare request body for sending'


originCall
                                .client
                                .requestPipeline
                                .execute(
                                    HttpRequestBuilder().apply {
                                        originCall.request
                                    },
                                    originCall.body()
                                )